# Is there a log of permission requests/grants?

Tags: permissions, logging

Does Android keep a log of permission request from apps?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether a hard copy is stored somewhere in system but the one in memory can be looked by this command:

```
adb shell dumpsys appops
```

This would give a dump of apps (recognized by package name and UID) having granted or rejected runtime permissions requested by them.